# Can I add a footnote (or a paragraph of text) to an index?

Tags: footnotes, indexing

Writing about a phenomenon X, I used X acronim too many times throughout the document. I also used many other acronims. It seems that instead of including a long list of page numbers for the acronim X, I could instead say in a paragraph above an index, but preferably in a footnote to an index something along the lines that "as the topic of the document is X and it is mentioned too many times, it is not included in the index".

Would appreciate help changing the MWE below to print a footnote below the index (preferred), or a paragraph of text above the index.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

This document is about X. But it also mentions Y\index{Y}, Z\index{Z}, as well as A\index{A}, B\index{B} and C\index{C}.

% As this document is about X and it is used too many times throughtout the text, it is not included in the index.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the package `imakeidx` and use `\indexprologue{As this document is about X and it is used too many times throughout the text, it is not included in the index.}`.  See package documentation for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a hook `\preindexhook`, which can be redefined to insert stuff between the index title and the index entries:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

This document is about X. But it also mentions Y\index{Y}, Z\index{Z}, as
well as A\index{A}, B\index{B} and C\index{C}.

\renewcommand*{\preindexhook}{%
  As this document is about X and it is used too many times throughout the
  text, it is not included in the index.\par
  \indexspace
}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

I think the best place for the additional text for the index is between the index title and the entries. As footnote the text is only disrupting the entry list.

Since the default index uses two-column layout, a footnote is a little trickier.
The following example puts the footnote as one-column footnote on the first page
of the index. The two-column entries are set by environment `multicols` with balanced columns:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifindex@multicols
\renewenvironment{theindex}{%
  \clearforchapter
  \if@twocolumn
    \@restonecolfalse
  \else
    \@restonecoltrue
  \fi
  \ifonecolindex
    \onecolumn
    \chapter*{\indexname}
    \preindexhook
  \else
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{\indexrule}%
    \setlength{\columnsep}{\indexcolsep}%
    %\twocolumn[
      \@makeschapterhead{\indexname\footnotemark}%
      \footnotetext{\indexfootnotetext}%
      \preindexhook
    %]
    \index@multicolstrue 
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
  \fi
  \indexmark
  \ifnoindexintoc\else
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}%
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{indextitlepagestyle}\parindent\z@
  \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
  \let\item\@idxitem
}{%
  \ifindex@multicols
    \end{multicols}%
  \else
    \if@restonecol\onecolumn\else\twocolumn\fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\makeindex
\newcommand*{\indexfootnotetext}{%
  As this document is about X and it is used too many times throughout the
  text, it is not included in the index.%
}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{First chapter}
  This document is about X. But it also mentions Y\index{Y}, Z\index{Z}, as
  well as A\index{A}, B\index{B} and C\index{C}.

  \printindex
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result footnote]

Comment: I tried to use a combination of above and a footnote, but no footnote appears after the index. Can I not have a footnote after the index?

Comment: Interesting enough, the index was growing and at one point there appeared a blank page after the index, which had a footnote separation line at the bottom.

Comment: The index was growing and finally spilled into the 2nd page, and the footnote line disappeared. Is there any way to avoid the blank page with the footnote line and no footnote at some point when the index is almost going to fill the first page?

Comment: @ajeh I would avoid a footnote: (a) It is disrupting the index entries. (b) It needs a footnote marker. A title with a footnote marker is ugly. (c) Either the text should be read, then the index prologue is the right place, or it does not need to be read, then it can be omitted. (d) It's no fun doing it in LaTeX because of the two-column mode of the index entries. A footnote in one column is even uglier.

Comment: It seems that this hook is not defined for the `article` class. (And also not in `scrartcl`, which I'm using right now.)... but I just realized there is bundle named after you to cope with this!